# Blender Python Material search

Tags: python, list, blender

How do I tell a script to compare a string with the names of all materials? This following code does not work:

```
for i in len(bpy.data.materials):
    if str(color) == bpy.data.materials[i].name:
        mat = bpy.data.materials[i]
        mesh.materials.append(mat)
        break
```

Error:

```
TypeError: 'int' object is not iterable (line 1)
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That first line needs to be changed to `for i in range(len(bpy.data.materials)):`.

Alternatively, you could write the following instead:

```
for mat in bpy.data.materials:
    if str(color) == mat.name:
        mesh.materials.append(mat)
        break
```